# DOS/sqlplus "Handle is invalid" error?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, dos, sqlplus

I have the following batch script:

```
sqlplus ms/ms@orcl < drop.sql
sqlplus ms/ms@orcl < create.1.0.sql
```

This works fine when I double click on the bat file in Windows Explorer and run it.

But when I type the command name from the DOS prompt I get an error:

```
C:\>create.bat

C:\>sqlplus ms/ms@orcl  0<drop.sql
The handle is invalid.

C:\>sqlplus ms/ms@orcl  0<create.1.0.sql
The handle is invalid
```

Any ideas?

---

**Update**: Made the change to use `@` instead of `<`.  This gets around the error but now the script only executes the first file and then leaves you at the `SQL>` prompt.  To get the second file to execute you have to type `exit` at the prompt, then the second file runs.  Not sure how to get both files to execute. ??

Comment: Looks like the batch script you're running from the command line has some extra 0's. 0 is an invalid handle, thus the error messages.
Use shoover's solution - the @ is a parameter to sqlplus that tells it to run the given sql script.

Comment: Tried it, not luck.  Updated post.

Comment: See my comment below Jason's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want SQL*PLUS to execute a script, a better way than command-line redirection is the @ syntax:

```
sqlplus ms/ms@orcl @drop.sql
sqlplus ms/ms@orcl @create.1.0.sql
```

Also read up on the @@ syntax, which you can use to execute a .sql script from another .sql script in the same directory.

```
SQL> help @
SQL> help @@
```

Comment: What I did was create a new `create.sql` script which calls my two scripts.  I execute `create.sql` using the `@` sign.

Answer (score 0):

> Made the change to use @ instead of <.
>   This gets around the error but now the
>   script only executes the first file
>   and then leaves you at the SQL>
>   prompt. To get the second file to
>   execute you have to type exit at the
>   prompt, then the second file runs. Not
>   sure how to get both files to execute.
>   ??

I ended up writing a python script to run sql plus and then exit it to get around this issue.  I have yet to find any way around that limitation.  Although you would only have to deal with the issue once if you use `@@` as was suggested.  You would just have to run the second script from the first script.

Comment: If you know you're going to be running your scripts from SQL*PLUS only, you can add the QUIT; command at the bottom of your scripts.  That causes SQL*PLUS to exit.